# How to change arabic font for 15.10?

Tags: fonts, arabic

How to change Arabic font for 15.10? Cause the font in Facebook and Other sites is too bad :D

Comment: what do you mean by those fonts are too bad? You cannot change the font on a website, because they are defined by the website makers

Comment: you should make sure you have installed these packages from Ubuntu Software Center [urdu](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/language-support-fonts-ur/) , [persian](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/language-support-fonts-fa/), [arabic](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/language-support-fonts-ar/)

Comment: the fonts are very big compared and different to firefox in windows in all websites

Comment: @HossamAhmed, Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. could you [edit] the question and add some screenshots to compare and issue description. Please, avoid using comments for important info.

Comment: @Sneetsher i got the problem, it was the most sites are working on base fonts from windows like arial and times ..etc so i installed the default windows fonts and now it works fine. Thanks :)